# Routing cyrillic characters in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

How to allow the routing of cyrillic characters in codeigniter ?

Comment: I just counted: you've received **12** answers to the **10** questions you've asked. **AND YOU'VE ACCEPTED ONE**. Please go accept some answers before you ask more questions.

Answer (score 4):

Let's say for example you have the following route:

```
controller/action/someId
```

Let's Now say your **controller** you want to be **контролер** (in cyrillic or any other alphabet, so you get:

```
контролер/action/someId
```

Obviously you can not name your *Controller class* "**Контролер**", so you must do it trough *application/config/routes.php*

Sadly if you go there and type:

```
$route['контролер/action/(:num)'] = "controller/action/$1";
```

to match the route, Codeigniter will NOT use **controller** but will throw an error.

It took me some time to understand that Codeigniter gets an encoded URL something looking like %5%6%77%24

So to match the encoded string you have to have it encoded also in your *routes.php*.

You can do that, and keep code readable if you enter the route like that:

```
$route[rawurlencode('контролер').'/action/(:num)'] = "controller/action/$1";
```

This will encode the part of the URL that's in non-latin characters, you should use that also in links, just to make sure all is parallel and does not fail somewhere along the line so:

```
<?php echo site_url( rawurlencode('контролер').'/action/'.$id ); ?>
```

Hope it helps! It worked flawlessly for me : ))

Answer (score 0):

In file `application/config/config.php` find `$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';` and add there each one allowed character – for example:

```php
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя';
```

Comment: PHP regular expressions doesn't support that. I suppose no one programming language does. Some languages supports [unicode](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html).

Comment: Oh, really? `$str = "яаафаф"; preg_match("([а-я]*)",$str,$matches); var_dump($matches);` gives me `array(1) { [0]=> string(6) "яаафаф" }` win7x86, PHP 5.2.12-ts, Apache 2.0.53

Comment: @J0HN although this **MAY** be working with you, this is not always the case. Sometimes with apache and `.htaccess` rewrite, you can't define `а-я` as a regex, thus you need to add all letters. This is the case in some versions of `php` as well.